# bootstrap navbar mobile mode inline menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

im not quite sure if this was asked / answered already, but seems i cant get any result from search.

my problem is i want to have an interface like m.facebook (the one with inbox/notifs icon) visible on mobile layout of bootstrap. i have done this far but it seems to be having padding/alignment issue:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span></button>

<a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo URL;?>"><img src="<?php echo URL;?>img/logo.png" alt="Park"/></a>
  <ul class="list-inline">
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> <span class="badge disabled btn-info">3</span></a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> <span class="badge disabled btn-info">11</span></a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> <span class="badge disabled btn-info">23</span></a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

when run it display the icons below the brand(logo) on desktop mode and icons display in-line when on mobile mode but misaligned.

when i change the `<ul class="list-inline">` to `<ul class="navbar-brand list-inline">`, it acts on reverse (i.e. desktop mode display in-line icons with the brand(logo) but on mobile it is below the brand(logo)).

ps. im still needing the hamburger (pulldown) menu for other use.

thanks.

Comment: Looks fine to me both on mobile/desktop when adding `navbar-brand` to the  `ul`. [See my example.](http://www.bootply.com/aX0SOe4eiz) Could you elaborate how you want it to look like?

Comment: im using mobile phone the layout gets destroyed its not the same with whats on bootply :(

Comment: @Topr try [link](http://kozadik.com/Home.htm) its OK on desktop but not on mobile

Comment: Isn't the problem that your logo is too wide on mobile? If you for example set a `max-width:60px;` on the logo everything is displayed on one row.